# How can we remove a page from Navigation Stack in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Is there a way to remove a page from Navigation stack in windows phone 8.1 universal app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is Frame.BackStack Property. You can use RemoveAt() Method to remove.